# Spinning Image in Windows Forms (C#)

Tags: c#, winforms, animation, spinning

I'm working in a music player, where I want the album art of the current song to be spinning in a circular picture box, just a vynil turntable.

I already have the circular picturebox, I made one attempt to make it spin, but it is spinning roughly, it doesn't look smooth. So I don't know if I am using the wrong parameters or if something is wrong in my code.

Used code from here: 
[Rotating image around center C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27431345/rotating-image-around-center-c-sharp)

Hope you can help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't rotate the image at all.  Just rotate the **Graphics** itself that you paint the Image on in the Paint() event of that surface.  First you Translate to the center of your PictureBox, then Rotate the desired amount.  Finally you paint your image at negative coordinates using half the width/height of the image itself.  Do this in a Timer event that increments the amount to rotate by and then draw as above.

Comment: I did that, see the thread I posted. But the spinning doesn't look smooth. Try it yourself and you will see what I'm talking about.

Comment: Your posted thread is creating a new, rotated bitmap each time, which I wouldn't be doing.  Approximately what are the dimensions of your image and how often do you want to rotate it?

Comment: Oh now I get it, I apologize. Dimensions may vary but they will always be square (300x300, 1000x1000, 4096x4096, etc). Rotation will be continous until the playing song ends. I want it to look as a vynil disc spinning around its center. The problem is that the animation does not look smooth, rotation looks rough, stepped, as if I am spinning 10 float per 1 second, when my parameters say 10 float per 10 milliseconds.

Comment: For large images like that, DigheadsFerke is absolutely right.  You will not get smooth fast "spinning" with images that big.  If your images stay relatively small (maybe under 500x500?), and you rotate in steps of maybe 10 degrees, then it might look okay refreshing on a Timer with an interval of 50 milliseconds.  I'll post an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WinForms graphical API is very limited and thats why the whole platform is obsolete. WPF is more capable for graphical presentation because there is a hardware acceleration and DirectX behind that.
My opinion if you are creating entertaining solutions use at minimum WPF. If your aim is purely business then WinForms is more than enough.

Comment: Oh Ok. So can you guide me where I can begin to achieve what I want in WPF?

Comment: Reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748373(v=vs.110).aspx Tutorial: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/69048/Tutorial-Creating-a-Lookless-WPF-Custom-Rotate-Con

Answer (score 1):

This was really smooth for me with a PictureBox size of 150x150 and an image size of 200x200:

[image: Rotating Vinyl Record]

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private int Angle;
    private Image Art; // you may need to resample larger images to a smaller image dynamically!
    private int AngleStep = 20;
    private System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath Vinyl = new System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath();

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Interval = 50;
        Art = Properties.Resources.AlbumArt2; // image as embedded resource (or from somewhere else)

        // larger circle with the center cut out: (like a vinyl record)
        Vinyl.AddEllipse(pictureBox1.ClientRectangle);
        Rectangle rc = new Rectangle(pictureBox1.Width / 2, pictureBox1.Height / 2, 1, 1);
        rc.Inflate(10, 10);
        Vinyl.AddEllipse(rc);

        pictureBox1.Paint += PictureBox1_Paint;
    }

    private void PictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics G = e.Graphics;
        G.SetClip(Vinyl);
        G.TranslateTransform(pictureBox1.Width / 2, pictureBox1.Height / 2); // move to the center
        G.RotateTransform(Angle); // rotate to the current angle
        G.DrawImage(Art, new Point(-(Art.Width / 2), -(Art.Height / 2))); // draw the image centered
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Enabled = !timer1.Enabled;
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Angle = Angle + AngleStep;
        if (Angle >= 360)
        {
            Angle = Angle - 360;
        }
        pictureBox1.Refresh();
    }

}
```

Play with it and see if it'll work for you.  You'll definitely need to make dynamic smaller images from those larger ones.  If you want performance graphics and animations, move to WPF as DigheadsFerke suggested.

Comment: Yeah it works good, but not with images larger than 500px. So, I will move to WPF. Thanks for your time and examples.